# Setting Caret Position to End of Multiple Textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set the caret of a number of `TextBoxes` to the end of the text one after another after all have been populated with text. I understand that there is a number of ways of setting this but all appear to require the `TextBox` to be in `Focus`. My issue is that doing this all at once means that only the last `TextBox` is affected. I believe this is because the UI is only affected all at once so only one `Focus` is applied. Any workaround to set multiple caret positionings at once?

```
        txtImagesFolder.Select(txtImagesFolder.Text.Length, 0);
        txtImagesFolder.Focus();

        txtTextFolder.Select(txtTextFolder.Text.Length, 0);
        txtTextFolder.Focus();
```

Comment: There only _is_ one caret. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried moving your selection *after* setting the focus?

Comment: @CodeCaster All of the Textboxes should be showing the righthand side of their text. If a TextBox has more text than width the left hand side will become hidden to the left. If you populate a TextBox with text the left hand text is still visible, the right is hidden. I would like all right hand side text visible. Focus isn't actually an issue/concern. It just appears to be necessary to set the caret.

Comment: If you want whatever is typed to affect each textbox then you need to look at the change event for the control and duplicate the text between the different textboxes.

Comment: @Paul Good suggestion but yes I've tried setting Focus first also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scroll each `TextBox` to the right like this:

```
txtImagesFolder.CaretIndex = txtImagesFolder.Text.Length - 1;
var rect = t1.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(txtImagesFolder.CaretIndex);
txtImagesFolder.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(rect.Right);
```

Create a method and call it for each `TextBox`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollToRight(txtImagesFolder);
    ScrollToRight(txtTextFolder);
}

private void ScrollToRight(TextBox textBox)
{
    textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length - 1;
    var rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(textBox.CaretIndex);
    textBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(rect.Right);
}
```

> This appears to work for me. However, a follow on issue I'm having is that just before I call my ScrollToRights I'm uncollapsing a StackPanel that holds them. This means that the rect does not receive any co ordinates. I tried calling this from the IsVisibleChanged event of the StackPanel but this of course also occurs before the UI update. Any thoughts on a workaround?

Use the dispatcher:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ScrollToRight(txtImagesFolder);
        ScrollToRight(txtTextFolder);
    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

Comment: This appears to work for me. However, a follow on issue I'm having is that just before I call my `ScrollToRight`s I'm uncollapsing a `StackPanel` that holds them. This means that the rect does not receive any co ordinates. I tried calling this from the `IsVisibleChanged` event of the `StackPanel` but this of course also occurs before the UI update. Any thoughts on a workaround?